# OpenStack API token lifespan extension

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon

All,

OpenStack API issues token after successful authentication. However, it is only valid for 1 hour.

Is there any workaround or possibility to extend token's lifespan?

Thanks & Regards,
Ganesh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the solutions used by [Heat](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Heat), the OpenStack orchestration engine.

Heat needs to be able to execute actions on behalf of a user at some point in the future. Heat cannot simply store a token because, as you have stated, tokens expire.

Heat offers two solutions to "deferred authentication".

- [Keystone Trusts](http://docs.openstack.org/admin-guide-cloud/content/section_orchestration-keystone-trusts-authorization.html)
- [Stored passwords](http://docs.openstack.org/admin-guide-cloud/content/section_orchestration-password-authorization.html)

There are lots of details about how Heat handles this [here](http://hardysteven.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/heat-auth-model-updates-part-1-trusts.html) and [here](http://hardysteven.blogspot.com/2014/04/heat-auth-model-updates-part-2-stack.html).

There are some API examples of keystone trusts on the [eNovance blog](http://techs.enovance.com/5858/role-delegation-in-keystone-trusts), and some more over [here](http://elmiko.github.io/2014/06/10/keystone-trust-delegation.html).